# Batch script to check if a folder exists. If yes, then copy a file from another folder to this folder

Tags: batch-file, conditional-statements, copy-paste

I am new to programming, with no background whatsoever.
I am creating a batch script which will create folders based on user input.
Then it will copy files from a shared server to the local folders that have been created.

I have the following script:

```
    @ECHO OFF
REM *********************************************************************
REM **This will create directories and Copy Files for your project**
REM *********************************************************************

ECHO Plese enter the no. between 1 to 5 only
set /p input=[Please enter:1-Belgium, 2-Austria, 3-France, 4-Germany, 5-Greece]

if %input%==1 md BEL

if %input%==2 md AUT

if %input%==3 md FRA

if %input%==4 md DEU

if %input%==5 md GRE

if %input%==1 cd BEL

if %input%==2 cd AUT

if %input%==3 cd FRA

if %input%==4 cd DEU

if %input%==5 cd GRE

::ECHO Please enter the no. between 1 to 5 only

:END

set /p userinput=[Please enter your folder name]

mkdir %userinput%

cd %userinput%

set /p input=[Press 1 for 1.0, 2 for 2.0]

if %input%==1 md Folder1
if %input%==2 md Folder2
IF EXIST .\Folder1 xcopy "C:\ProgramFiles\kasras01\file2.txt"
```

All along, the code does well, until it comes to the part where I need to check if a folder exists. If it does, then I need to copy a file from another location to this folder.
But I am unable to get it to work. I think my syntax is incorrect.
How do I get it to work?
Grateful for any help.

Comment: Because you are looking for specific input at two of your input prompts you should instead use the `Choice` command for those. _(for usage information type `Choice /?` at the command prompt)_. When requesting input using `Set /P`, the end user is free to just hit the enter key or type whatever they want, so the code which follows that input should ensure that an entry was both made, and that it was also a valid Windows directory name.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line of your posted script should look more like this:

```bat
IF EXIST "Folder1" XCOPY "C:\ProgramFiles\kasras01\file2.txt" "Folder1\" /Y
```

Here also is a rewritten example using both `Choice` for the controlled input and `Set /P` with checks for the uncontrolled input:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
CD /D "%~dp0" 2>Nul || Exit /B
REM **************************************************************************
REM ** This will create directories and copy a single file for your project **
REM **************************************************************************
Echo 1. Belgium&Echo 2. Austria&Echo 3. France&Echo 4. Germany&Echo 5. Greece
Choice /C 12345 /M "Which one"
If ErrorLevel 5 MD "GRE" 2>Nul & CD "GRE"
If ErrorLevel 4 MD "DEU" 2>Nul & CD "DEU"
If ErrorLevel 3 MD "FRA" 2>Nul & CD "FRA"
If ErrorLevel 2 MD "AUT" 2>Nul & CD "AUT"
If ErrorLevel 1 MD "BEL" 2>Nul & CD "BEL"
:DirPick
Echo(&Echo Please type your chosen directory name
Set /P "UserInput= then press enter: "
If Not Defined UserInput Echo Empty names are disallowed& GoTo DirPick
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^\^/^:^*^?^"^|^<^>^ EOL^= %%A In ("[!UserInput!]"
) Do Echo Disallowed character detected& Set "UserInput=" & GoTo DirPick
EndLocal & MD "%UserInput%" 2>Nul & CD "%UserInput%"
Choice /C 12 /N /M "Press 1 for 1.0, 2 for 2.0"
XCopy "C:\ProgramFiles\kasras01\file2.txt" "Folder%ErrorLevel%\" /Y>Nul
```

*The script is  currently designed to use its own location as the base for the new directories etc. If you wish for a different base directory, change `%~dp0` only on line `3` to the path you require.
The `XCopy` command at the bottom currently has no checking mechanism, this means that if `"C:\ProgramFiles\kasras01\file2.txt"` doesn't exist, `Folder[1|2]` will not be created either! (Otherwise it would create `Folder[1|2]` and copy `"C:\ProgramFiles\kasras01\file2.txt"` into it.)*

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXIST .\Folder1\ xcopy ...
```

Your code creates (eg) `folder1` in the *current* directory, then looks for `folder1` in the *parent* directory. Adding the `\` looks for a *directory* only, not a file.

Are you aware that the `xcopy` will copy the file into the *current* directory, not the `folder1` subdirectory?

---

```
xcopy "C:\ProgramFiles\kasras01\file2.txt" ".\folder%input%\"
```

should create and copy. You'd no doubt want to validate `input` is `1` or `2` first.

Comment: The ..\ was a typo. Sorry about that. xcopy is copying the file into the current directory. I wanted to know how I can direct it to the subdirectory.

Comment: Hence, use copy-paste, don't retype. Quicker, too.

Answer (score 0):

I need to check if a folder OR a file exists in a directory and I need to distinguish between them.

I found using \nul to be unreliable in some cases (Windows 10) - meaning that checking `IF EXIST "%foldername%\nul"` returned true regardless if there was a file or folder with the same name.

I found out that in my case, using `IF EXIST "%foldername%\"` (without `nul`) worked fine.

Snippet:

```
IF EXIST "%fname%" (
goto :f1
) ELSE (
goto :f2
)

:f1
IF EXIST "%fname%\" (
echo Folder with the same name already exists!
echo Cannot continue!
) ELSE (
echo File with the same name already exists!
echo Cannot continue!
)
```